# Error when using the trained "model.pth" file in transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, transfer-learning, torchvision

I'm working on a deep learning project. I do not have any problems with training and classification, but when I try to add a section for transfer learning to my project, I get an error.
The model I used in training is as follows;

```
class SimpleCNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_classes=numClasses):
    super(SimpleCNN, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
    self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128 * 56 * 56, 512)
    self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()  # Değişiklik burada
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.relu1(x)
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.relu2(x)
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = x.view(-1, 128 * 56 * 56)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = self.relu3(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    return x
```

I know that the layers of the model I trained and the model I used in transfer learning should be compatible, but I could not achieve this. I will write below the python file I created for transfer learning. Can you help me find out where the problem is?

```
import json
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models
from torch import optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torchvision.transforms import transforms
from model import SimpleCNN

with open("config.json", "r") as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

data_path_main = config["data_path_main"]
input_channels = config["inputChannels"]

alexnet = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
custom_model = SimpleCNN(num_classes=input_channels)
custom_model.conv1 = alexnet.features[0]

custom_model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(alexnet.classifier[1].in_features, input_channels)
)

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

dataset = ImageFolder(root=data_path_main, transform=transform)

total_size = len(dataset)
train_size = int(0.7 * total_size)
val_size = int(0.15 * total_size)
test_size = total_size - train_size - val_size

train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size,     test_size])

batch_size = 64
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

model = custom_model
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

num_epochs = 10
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()

    epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader)
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {epoch_loss}')

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 't-model.pth')
```

Comment: The error I got: RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 401408]' is invalid for input of size 1384448